# format() is a nondeterministic built-in string function... right?

Tags: sql-server

Before I post a connect item regarding the lack of documentation about this, will someone confirm that I am not simply missing something here?

On the docs page where `format` is listed as a string function:

> "All built-in string functions are deterministic." - [String Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql)

There is also no mention of `format` being nondeterministic on related pages:

- [Deterministic and Nondeterministic Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions)
- [FORMAT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql)

---

However, when attempting to create a persisted computed column:

```
create table t (date_col date); 
insert into t values (getdate());
alter table t add date_formatted_01 as format(date_col,'YYYY') persisted;
```

Returns the following error:

> Computed column 'date_formatted_01' in table 't' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

The documentation states that

> If the culture argument is not provided, the language of the current
>   session is used.

but adding a culture argument doesn't change things

This also fails

```
alter table t add date_formatted_02 as format(date_col, 'd', 'en-US' ) persisted
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ZMS22966

dbfiddle.uk demo: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_next&fiddle=7fc57d1916e901cb561b551af144aed6

Comment: This also fails: `alter table #t add date_formatted_01 as CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), FORMAT(date_col, 'YYYY', 'en-US')) persisted;`. Not sure why `FORMAT` isn't deterministic, especially when specifying the culture. The `date_formatted` column _can_ be `VARCHAR(20)` (still persisted) and set via Trigger using `FORMAT`. Or SQLCLR works. Using the [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/) SQLCLR library (that I wrote), you can do `ALTER TABLE SQL#.t ADD date_formatted_03 AS SQL#.Date_Format(date_col, 'd', 'en-US') PERSISTED;` (table is owned by SQL# since table and function owner need to be the same).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function isn't necessarily deterministic or nondeterministic. There are some functions which can be deterministic [depending on how they are used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions):

> The following functions are not always deterministic, but can be used in indexed views or indexes on computed columns when they are specified in a deterministic manner.

`CAST` and `CONVERT` are such examples. Based on the testing that you've done so far, I think that it's fair to say that `FORMAT` is not always deterministic, despite being a string function. If you want to know if it's sometimes deterministic the only technique I can think of is to try enough different ways to call it until you are satisfied. For example, let's consider `FORMAT` as applied to numbers. There are only ten different [numeric input types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql):

[image: numeric input types]

There also appear to be only [nine different numeric formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dwhawy9k.aspx). It's possible to try to create persisted columns for all possible combinations. Some code to do that is below:

```
DECLARE @FormatValue INT = 76767; -- change this if you want
DECLARE @FormatCulture VARCHAR(10) = 'en-US'; -- change this if you want
DECLARE @Format VARCHAR(1);
DECLARE @FormatType VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @SQLForColumn VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @TestNumber INT = 0;

BEGIN

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TargetTable;
    CREATE TABLE dbo.TargetTable (ID INT);

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ColumnAddResults;
    CREATE TABLE #ColumnAddResults (
    FormatType VARCHAR(10),
    [Format] VARCHAR(1), 
    Succeeded VARCHAR(1), 
    ErrorMessage VARCHAR(1000)
    );

    drop table if exists #Types;
    create table #Types (FormatType VARCHAR(10));

    INSERT INTO #Types VALUES
    ('bigint'), ('int'), ('smallint'), ('tinyint'), ('decimal')
    , ('numeric'), ('float'), ('real'), ('smallmoney'), ('money');

    drop table if exists #Formats;
    create table #Formats ([Format] VARCHAR(1));

    INSERT INTO #Formats VALUES 
    ('C'), ('D'), ('E'), ('F'), ('G'), ('N'), ('P'), ('R'), ('X');

    DECLARE format_statements CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT #Types.FormatType, #Formats.[Format]
    FROM #Formats
    CROSS JOIN #Types;

    OPEN format_statements;

    FETCH NEXT FROM format_statements   
    INTO @FormatType, @Format;  

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN
        SET @TestNumber = @TestNumber + 1;
        SET @SQLForColumn = 'alter table dbo.TargetTable add NewColumn' + CAST(@TestNumber AS VARCHAR(10))
        + ' as FORMAT(CAST(' +  CAST(@FormatValue AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' AS ' + @FormatType + '), '
        + '''' + @Format + ''', ''' + @FormatCulture + ''') persisted';

        BEGIN TRY
            EXEC (@SQLForColumn);
            INSERT INTO #ColumnAddResults VALUES (@FormatType, @Format, 'Y', NULL);
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            INSERT INTO #ColumnAddResults VALUES (@FormatType, @Format, 'N', ERROR_MESSAGE());
        END CATCH;

        PRINT @SQLForColumn;

        FETCH NEXT FROM format_statements   
        INTO @FormatType, @Format;  
    END;

    CLOSE format_statements;  
    DEALLOCATE format_statements;  

    SELECT * FROM dbo.TargetTable;
    SELECT * FROM #ColumnAddResults;
    DROP TABLE #ColumnAddResults;

END;
```

Here's a sample of the output:

[image: test code output]

I wasn't able to get any of the columns to be added to the table for a few input values and cultures. I did not exhaustively try all possible cultures because I can't find a list of them within SQL Server.

At minimum it seems safe to conclude that the documentation regarding the determinism of `FORMAT` is incorrect, so I would recommend submitting a connect item for it.

Answer (score 7):

The [`FORMAT` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) has now been [updated](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/commit/5520f9460df394a07cc9c547e1e81278fde5119d?short_path=3900e60#diff-3900e6001447f2af63e05ef98f355f9a) (in response to your [Connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3134874/)) to say:

> The `FORMAT` function is nondeterministic.

Likewise, [String Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql) now includes:

> All built-in string functions except `FORMAT` are deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a regular user of sqlserver, so I might be mistaken, but my guess is that format is not a string function. According to the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql

format takes either a date type or a numeric type as argument. If all you want to do is to grab the year-part of a date, cant you use the year function?

```
alter table t 
    add date_formatted_01 as year(date_col) persisted;
```

if you want a string representation:

```
alter table t 
    add date_formatted_01 as cast(year(date_col) as char(4)) persisted;
```

Comment: It's listed as a string function in the docs.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj0T2.png

Comment: @MartinSmith, interesting. Personally I find it counter intuitive and it also becomes logically inconsistent with "All built-in string functions are deterministic."

Comment: @Lennart I appreciate the alternative to the example, but the example wasn't important.

Comment: @SqlZim, I figured that your example was just an example but I added an alternative just in case. I'm not sure what your question is exactly, is it whether format is a string function or not, whether it's deterministic or not, or whether all of that is badly documented?